# Magento 2 - Marketing Conversion Tag Troubleshooting

Tags: magento2, conversion, coding

I work at an agency with a client trying to put a conversion code with dynamic parameters into the purchase success page. The code requires Magento 2's unique identifiers to create the hit that relays the info to my ad platform. I need the parameters for: `cart subtotal` and for `product name`.

As example, Shopify uses `{{checkout.subtotal_price}}` for subtotal values.

Can anyone reply with these values?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use extension like this

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-checkout-success-misc-script

But depending on how bespoke you might have to write something custom

https://github.com/DominicWatts/GoogleEcommerceTracking

Comment: so there is no standard taxonomy we can use without a plugin or extension? I believe the coders tried a custom solution, but my ad platform has not been able to read that format and register the values in reporting.

Comment: No there isn’t without extension

Comment: I work for an agency and we frequently have to code such functionality. It's not too difficult.

Comment: In your agency, what ad platform did/do you work with? Google, Trade Desk, Centro, etc?

Comment: Generally google, Facebook and bing. Google extension is built in. Facebook has a extensive officialish extension. Google ships with M2. Very early versions of M2 it was was basic. I don't think you got commerce tracking option. So far only stuff had to create is random remarketing snippets. Nothing well known and most have disappeared as quickly as they appeared.